# Posting to Ruby service with Python

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, post

I've got a *Python* script that is posting some data to a *Rails* app. The issue I seem to be having is my parameter is not being formatted correctly. How would be the proper way to build the parameters in *Python*?

*Python* code:

```
request = urllib.urlencode(dict({'temperature_reading': {'CelciusReading':temperature}}))
```

print request

What the log file says the rails server is getting:

```
Parameters: {"temperature_reading"=>"{'CelciusReading': 42.25}"}
```

What the log looks like when I do a post from the webpage itself:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MMbvXa3xA6NFU8Mf1Y2dagpm3GuBP3ZApdFXI55Ql00=", "temperature_reading"=>{"CelciusReading"=>"42.25"}, "commit"=>"Create Temperature reading"}
```

It seems the python is formatting it as `'CelciusReading': 42.25` when it should be `'CelciusReading'=>42.25` if I'm understand what is going on properly

Below is the error log if that's helpful to anyone:

> 2014-08-23T00:26:05.485205+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST
>   path="/temperature_readings" host=smokey-watch.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=e5641fd5-4ead-446d-883a-c800b05f4f11 fwd="98.17.210.4"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=22ms status=500 bytes=489
>   2014-08-23T00:26:05.480780+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   app/controllers/temperature_readings_controller.rb:73:in
>   `temperature_reading_params' 2014-08-23T00:26:05.480798+00:00
>   app[web.1]:  2014-08-23T00:26:05.466259+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST
>   "/temperature_readings" for 98.17.210.4 at 2014-08-23 00:26:05 +0000
>   2014-08-23T00:26:05.480775+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2014-08-23T00:26:05.480794+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   app/controllers/temperature_readings_controller.rb:28:in`create'
>   2014-08-23T00:26:05.480778+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined
>   method `permit' for "{'CelciusReading': 42.25}":String):
>   2014-08-23T00:26:05.480796+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2014-08-23T00:26:05.477662+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by
>   TemperatureReadingsController#create as HTML

Thank you all for your help

---

Great thought by *Ken Hampson* to make the temperature send as a string to make the data types match! I tried it, but it still does not seem to be liking it:

> 2014-08-23T11:56:58.602452+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST
>   "/temperature_readings" for 98.17.210.4 at 2014-08-23 11:56:58 +0000
>   2014-08-23T11:56:58.741053+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by
>   TemperatureReadingsController#create as HTML
>   2014-08-23T11:56:58.741064+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters:
>   {"temperature_reading"=>"{'CelciusReading': '38.875'}"}
>   2014-08-23T11:56:58.759571+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal
>   Server Error in 18ms 2014-08-23T11:56:58.760521+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2014-08-23T11:56:58.760523+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined
>   method `permit' for "{'CelciusReading': '38.875'}":String):
>   2014-08-23T11:56:58.760527+00:00 app[web.1]: 
>   2014-08-23T11:56:58.760525+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
>   app/controllers/temperature_readings_controller.rb:73:in`
>   temperature_reading_params' 2014-08-23T11:56:58.760528+00:00
>   app[web.1]:  2014-08-23T11:56:58.760526+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   app/controllers/temperature_readings_controller.rb:28:in `create'

Another thing I noticed that is different with the python script is that quotes surround the CelciusReading element: **"**{'CelciusReading': '38.875'}**"** versus Ruby looking like this: {"CelciusReading"=>"42.25"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out just posting with json is the easier way to go. Below is how I formatted the data for the json request:

```
data = {
        'temperature_reading': {'CelciusReading': temperature}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an issue with the `'CelciusReading': 42.25` versus `'CelciusReading'=>42.25` (that is to say, the colon vs. the `=>`).

That's simply a difference in how *hashes* are printed in *Python* versus *Ruby*.

However, what is different between the two, and what seems like could very well be the cause of the issue that is listed in the logs, is the value being assigned in each case. In the *Python* case, the hash value is *numeric*. In the *Ruby* case, the hash value is a *string*. The error implies that the *Ruby* method is looking for a string, and the fact that when you try it in the webpage itself, the hash value is a *string* also suggests that the parameter is expected to be a string.

So, I would suggest that you try the following *Python* code:

```
request = urllib.urlencode(
             dict({'temperature_reading': {'CelciusReading': str(temperature)}}))
```

This will cast the `temperature` value to a string, as the *Rails* method seems to be expecting.

Also, while it's a tangential issue, it may be necessary to also add `authenticity_token` and `utf8` parameters to your URL, although I don't think that's the crux of your issue as it relates to the error you listed above.

Comment: Great idea Ken! I gave it a try and it still is not working I've updated my answer with the new log file.